# Selecting a rendered component in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a card-flipping game. You need to click on two cards and they flip. If they are a pair, they stay flipped, if not, they flip back.

I have a component Card, that calls a flipCard function when clicked, and a GameService that keeps track of the overall game stats.

```
flipCard() {

if (this.gameService.flippedCards  < 2)
{
  this.flipped = true;
  this.gameService.flippedCards++;
  this.gameService.flippedCardsIds.push(this.cardNumber);

  if (this.gameService.flippedCards  == 2)
    if (this.gameService.flippedCardsIds[0][0] == this.gameService.flippedCardsIds[1][0])
    {
      // Flip back the cards
      // this.gameService.flippedCardsIds remembers the currently flipped card Ids
      this.gameService.flippedCards = 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the GameService structure:

```
cards = Array<number>();

flippedCards: number = 0;
flippedCardsIds = Array<string>();
index: number=0;

constructor() { }

generateRandomCards() {
  let newCard;
  newCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(16));
  if (this.cards.length < 16)
  {
    if (!this.cards.includes(newCard))
      this.cards.push(newCard);
  
    this.generateRandomCards();
  }

}
```

My question is, how can I keep track and re-flip my previous clicked card if they are not a pair? Using Ids won't work since the "flipped" attribute on the Card component won't be toggled.

For the current card I can just do this.flipCard().

Any help is welcome, I hope I was clear enough in my explanation

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by passing "this" when emiting the "flipCard" event to the parent component, and then storing it into an Array.